# NSPredicate use array as filter

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to use an array as a filter to search Core Data. The values that the fetchRequest returns should have an ID that is in the predicate's array.

```
let arrayOfFavoriteStampIDS = [302,2300,2309]
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemID IN %i", argumentArray: arrayOfFavoriteStampIDS)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemID IN %@", arrayOfFavoriteStampIDS)
```

`argumentArray` means something else for example

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemID == %i OR itemID == %i OR itemID == %i", argumentArray:arrayOfFavoriteStampIDS)
```

In this case each item in the array must match one `%i` placeholder.